# Router.use requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning express.js and doing an exercise of Router Mounting. I have latest versions of `node.js` and `express.js`. I have one main folder. This folder has node-modules folder, package and package-lock. This folder also has 3 files which i created.

main-folder:-
node-modules
package
package-lock
1.`index.js`
2.`router.js`
3.`home.js`

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const home = require('./home');
const user = require('./router');


app.use('/', home);
app.use('/router', user);

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to get a user");
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to create a user");
});

router.put('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to update a user");
});

router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to delete a user");
});

module.exports = router;
```

home.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/home', function(req,res){
    res.send("This is my Home page using Express Router");
});
```

Errors:-

TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn)
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object.

I have gone through all the topics in stackoverflow relating to the above mentioned error and tried every solution provided here in stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me.
I would appreciate your input!
Thank you!

Comment: You didn't export anything from home

Comment: Okay! Got it @Konrad. Thank you!.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your file name called home.js is a controller which is responsible for rendering the content which you want to display on the page....
You need to change your code in home.js index.js & router.js

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const home = require('./home');
const user = require('./router');


app.use('/', user);

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {homePage} = require('./home');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to get a user");
});
router.get('/home', homePage);

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to create a user");
});

router.put('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to update a user");
});

router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Please log to delete a user");
});

module.exports = router;
```

home.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const homePage = async (req,res) => {
    res.send("This is my Home page using Express Router");
};

module.exports = {homePage}
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: yes, Ehtisham bhai, you are right! I solved it with changing my home.js const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();

app.get('/home', function(req,res){
    res.send("This is my Home page using Express Router");
});
module.exports = router;

I reached to this solution after the hardwork of 8 hours. Your solution also works awesome. Thank you Ehtisham Bhai. Stay blessed!